# IE10 jquery undefined, also ignoring X-UA meta

Tags: php, jquery, magento, internet-explorer-10

We have designed a new site in Magento and everything looks good in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE 7,8 and 9 and 10 Compliance... however IE10 Standard is returning a jquery undefined error on the following noconflict script (line 32 character 5)

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

I have tried moving the script to the top of the head section, the bottom, just above and below the linked script. I have tried putting the noconflict into the script itself.  I have changed DOCTYPES thinking that was causing the issue.   Because it works fine in all other versions, I have also tried to use a X-UA for 9 and emulate 9  meta which both get ignored, as well as tried the .htaccess method.   To no avail.   IE10 just seems to do what it wants to do.

As I am not a jQuery pro and still learning the ins and outs of designing for IE10, I am at a loss and would appreciate any suggestions as to how to fix it.   The site is still in development **removed** (forgive me for not posting a proper link as we don't want it crawled just yet).

Comment: Try this: var $j = $.noConflict();

Comment: thank you frenchie for the suggestion, same result though -  jQuery undefined.

Comment: @frenchie if `$` is defined through jQuery, the object `jQuery` always is defined too.

Comment: @feeela: I'm just suggesting something to try. It's hard to guess what the problem is without looking at the code.

Comment: Try changing the line to var $j = $; and see what happens; you may not need the noConflict(); function, it might have just been inserted there by the programmer "in case".

Comment: @frenchie Thank you for the suggestion, I am actually the one who inserted the noConflict(); function because the dropdown menu and carousel were conflicting with one another.   The noConflict(); resolved that issue, but created the undefined error.   I have tried $j= $; per your suggestion but with the same results (actually not exactly the same result, it generates a string of undefined errors for nearly every JS include at the $j= $;).   Thanks again for the suggestion.  All things I had thought to try.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is not unique to IE 10 – I can see it too in Opera 12:

> Error thrown at line 6, column 2 in http://www.ecigexpress.com/newecx/:
>
> var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
>
> Das verlinkte Skript wurde nicht geladen. [The linked script was not loaded.]

You are trying to access the jQuery object before the jQuery JS file was included. Double-check the order of your JS includes. jQuery should come first.

Also if you use a construct like the follwing, you don't need to bother about the `noConflict()` setting at all:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    /* jQuery passes itself to the event handler function and we use
     * the local name $ for jQuery in this functions scope. */

     $( [] ) == jQuery( [] );

} );
```

Comment: It might have to do with the order the files are loaded?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion feeela.   I have tried moving the scripts around, but having trouble understanding which jQuery object is being accessed before which jQuery JS file.   I really appreciate your help.  I have updated the OP with a link to the zipped code files as it might make it easier.  I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: @gingabox There is only one jQuery file (jquery-1.8.0.min.js; which you are including). But if you are including a jQuery-file without knowing it – maybe that is the problem. Just randomly moving around script includes is not a solution. Try to learn some HTML and JS basics first.

Comment: @feeela  truly I appreciate the help, but there is not only one jquery file (and 1.8.0.min.js is not one of them actually).  There is jquery.jcarousel.min.js, jquery-1.8.2.min.js,  jquery.init.js, jquery.1.5.1.js, jqueryNoconfig.js and jquery.slides.min.js.  I was putting the jQuery prior to the other 40 or so JS files (most of them included via a php echo).   That was your suggestion (i.e. it wasn't random).   As for your final sentence... that is the whole point of asking questions, isn't it?

Comment: fixed... removed jquery-1.8.2.min.js and the noconfict(),  there is no conflict now and no undefined error.  Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @gingabox As I wrote above – try to learn the JS basics, then the jQuery basics. `jquery.jcarousel.min.js` is a jQuery plugin – not the library and if you had included `query-1.8.2.min.js` and `jquery.1.5.1.js` without knowing why you did so, that might be a problem…

Comment: @feeela I know its a plugin and not a library (it IS a jQuery file though)... thanks.   We all make mistakes in the learning process... as I said its why I asked the question in the first place.